# iOS 11 UINavigationBar extra height when using searchController

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uisearchbar, ios11, uinavigationitem, uisearchcontroller

I'm trying to add a search bar inside the navigation bar, here's my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var searchController : UISearchController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController:nil)
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false

        navigationItem.searchController = searchController

        definesPresentationContext = true
    }
}
```

It seems to work fine, but I can't find a way to reduce the navigation bar height. I don't need the extra space at the top.

[image]
[image]

**Here's what I'm trying to achieve** (default Messages search bar):

[image]